# Failed to precompile flutter_launcher_icons:main:

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

So I tried using flutter_launcher_icons to automatically change the launcher icon of my simple interest calculator app.

This is my code in pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.1

dev_dependencies:

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.0"

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

The Error I got after running flutter pub get &
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

```
Failed to precompile flutter_launcher_icons:main:
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.8.1/lib/utils.dart:1:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/
pub.dartlang.org/image-2.1.19/lib/image.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:image/image.dart';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.8.1/lib/android.dart:4:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hoste
d/pub.dartlang.org/image-2.1.19/lib/image.dart': The system cannot find the path specified.

import 'package:image/image.dart';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.8.1/lib/utils.dart:3:1: Error: Type 'Image' not found.
Image createResizedImage(int iconSize, Image image) {
^^^^^
                                                 ^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_launcher_icons-0.8.1/lib/ios.dart:93:1: Error: Type 'Image' not found.
Image createResizedImage(IosIconTemplate template, Image image) {
^^^^^
pub finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not import `flutter_launcher_icons` package correctly under `dev_dependencies`. You should not use quotes("). You can edit that part with the following one:

```
dev_dependencies:

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.8.0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change it like that;

```
flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"
```

and no need to use that import 'package:image/image.dart';  if you take your image from assets no need to import it like that. you should create a file named assets and put image in it

after that just paste that in terminal.

```
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main
```

Comment: i've changed it to `flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon.png"`  , i've already created a folder named assets and icon.png is already in it.     Tried flutter `pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main` again but the same ERROR.

Comment: did you remove import 'package:image/image.dart';

Answer (score 0):

In my case the image package was not being correctly downloaded, so I went to ~\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\image-3.0.8 and cloned the rep from git: https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image

After that the command worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30010366)